# how to restrict certain value in devise sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In signup i have allowed one more parameter :role.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :address, :phone1, :phone2, :business, :role])
```

Now i would like to filter the role passed. If the role is "user" or "dealer" then the role is set otherwise if the role is "admin" then role is not set. How can i achieve this?

User model has role property as string. The reason behind not permitting "admin" role is, admins are created manually. Admin user is not permitted to be created through the user registration form. I appreciate any guide. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to keep the original `role` to use it somewhere in your controller? If not, you can just change `params` at the beginning of `configure_permitted_parameters`

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to implement check before creating new record in devise. You can achieve your goal my modifying your **user model** as below
(**Note: This check will work either you add new user from controller or console.**)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    after_initialize :check_role, :if => :new_record?

    def check_role
        if self.role != 'user' && self.role != 'dealer'
            self.role = ''
        end
     end
end
```

Comment: does this only prevent setting values through controllers? remember that we need to be able to set value via rails console

Comment: It prevents from everywhere. If you just want to prevent from controller then you have to overide devise registration controller